# Bracket importance when calling a C++ function that takes no arguments

Tags: c++, functional-programming, brackets

I have a question about functions that take no arguments in C++, and possibly also C.

I am writing a simple program, which has a class. That class has a certain static method. This is what the header file could look like:

```
class SampleClass {
public:
    SampleClass();
    ~SampleClass();
    static void CertainMethod();
}
```

The CertainMethod() takes no arguments, is static, and should print out "SAMPLETEXT". My question is, why do we still need the brackets when calling it? Here are two pieces of main():

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
SampleClass::CertainMethod();
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

and

```
int main(int argc, const char** argv) {
SampleClass::CertainMethod;
system("pause");
return 0;
}
```

The purpose of both snippets is to print out "SAMPLETEXT", which is done by CertainMethod. Both of them compile successfully, but only the first one works. There is a warning when compiling the second snippet: **warning C4551: function call missing argument list**.

Why do we still have to put in the brackets in order for it to work, even though the code compiles successfully without them, and the function does not take in any arguments?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`SampleClass::CertainMethod` is the name of a function.

The name of a function implicitly decays into a pointer to the function in many use contexts.

Suppose you had:

```
void foo( void(*)() )
```

which is a function `foo` that takes a pointer to a function.  Then

```
foo( SampleClass::CertainMethod )
```

would pass a pointer to `SampleClass::CertainMethod` to `foo` to do with it what it will.

`SampleClass::CertainMethod` cannot invoke the function, because then you could not talk about a pointer to it!

In your case, you are naming the function, then discarding it.  You are allowed to do this in C++ -- you can have a statement like this:

```
int a = 3, b = 5;
a+b;
```

that `a+b` adds `a` to `b`, then discards the result.  Expressions are legal statements.

This is also legal:

```
a;
```

which is a simple expression that evaluates to `3`, but does nothing with the value.

So your line was an expression that evaluated a pointer or reference to `SampleClass::CertainMethod`.  Warning-worthy, but still legal C++.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. What could be the use of an expression like
`SampleClass::CertainMethod;`
or
`a+b;`
if it does not do anything with the result?

Comment: @W.Nawrocki - In C, do you look at the return value from `printf`? Hardly anyone does. They just use `printf("Hello world\n");`. There are a number of expressions that do have a value but that value isn't of much use.

Comment: I know, but I wasn't asking about actually calling a function. My question is whether there is any point in `SampleClass::CertainMethod;` getting a function pointer and not doing anything with it or `a+b;` adding two values together and immediately discarding the result.

Comment: @W.Nawrocki no, which is why the compiler issues a warning -- you have an expression with no side effects you evaluated and then discarded the result.  The compiler does **not** however try to read your mind: the compiler accepts expressions as statements.  This makes the language specification easier.  It also checks your code for some simple and easy mistakes, and issues warnings for them.

Comment: You could have overloaded the + operator, in which case a+b could do something other than return a value. The compiler shouldn't (and in many cases couldn't) see what operator+ actually does and decide whether to let you use it.

Comment: @GeorgeT you cannot override `+` on `int,int`.  The types of the arguments matter to my point.

Comment: @Yakk: I'm aware of that but I still think the compiler shouldn't go checking for all this, except maybe as a warning. The fact that there is an operator+ is enough to make it valid.